# background to content script messaging: message sent before content script is ready

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, messaging

When trying to pass a message from the background script to the content script, I'm using

```
chrome.tabs.query(
  {active: true, currentWindow: true},
  function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
      tabs[0].id,
      {greeting: "hello"},
      function(response) {
        console.log(response.farewell);
      }
    );
});
```

in the background script and the corresponding listener

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting === "hello") {
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    }
  });
```

in the content script (according to [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)).

Now, I might want to send something to the content script when the web request of the current tab has finished, e.g.,

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
  // sender code from above
)
```

I found, however that the background script sends the message when the content script hasn't been injected into the page yet. Consequently, there is not reply.

How to fix this? Is there an event that I could listen for in the background script that tells me when the content script has been loaded?

Comment: What triggers your first snippet? For a race condition, it's important to know.

Comment: Also, _for the love of everything that is holy_, I hope you won't use the `greeting`/`farewell` in your code. This piece of sample code has become a true [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult) object in extension programming and it's mildly disgusting.

Comment: @Xan Clarified. And of course I'm not actually using `greeting`/`farewell`. :)

Comment: You say "of course", but I've seen people modify this code with the implicit assumption that those property names _matter_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The safest way is to send a message *from* the content script indicating that it is ready, and only then reply from the background page.

You can, for instance, add something like a queue per tab ID and push messages there, and when the message from that tab arrives feed the queue to it.

You could also try using programmatic injection instead of manifest injection:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "yourContentScript.js"}, function() {
  // After the above finishes executing
  /* your messaging code */
});
```

However, if you call that before the navigation is *committed*, i.e. before the context of the tab is actually changed (which can probably happen with `webRequest` events), your script will try to inject in the *previous* page and will be wiped by transition.